# How I create a View for more lists?

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, filter, view

It is my first question and I a noob in Sharepoint but I get a task to set a view for a list. I explain the idea. Our company has a teamsite where we can see who have task and who do this task.

Now I want to create a view that i can see my tasks only. The Problem is the list has under lists with task by a hyperlink to a other list.

Can I set a view with a filter about more list in sharepoint?

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I click on "Werk" in the first picture i jump to picture 2 and I want a view for all lists.

I need help :(

Comment: the pictures dont work :(

Comment: Pics are working fine for me ... As an aside, if I'm understanding you correctly, you are looking to be able to click on the major task titles (ie: 2.0 Werke) and have it drop into a list view of it's own? I don't know how to do it myself, but would hope someone can help with a little more info.

Comment: I want to make a view of all tasks in the main list and in the under lists.

Comment: the list must show me all my tasks of all lists.

Comment: So, instead of a view, you want to see "all" tasks from "all" lists (showing tasks)? Sounds more like you want to create a page for which you can view everything at once. I would suggest creating a page with multiple data connections which would show all or tasks ... but am unsure if this is really what you want. I know the language barrier is posing an issue here. I apologize for not having a complete understanding of your needs.